How can I fix the following error "Invalid JSON body","errorCode":"oanda::rest::core::ClientRequestException" with OANDA trading platform?
I am having a hard time figuring out what could be wrong with my POST request to OANDA. I have been trying to submit limit and stop orders with no success so far. In terms of setup I am using Python 3.10 and the Requests package on a Windows 10 machine.
Here is my Python code that returns the following error message:
b'{"errorMessage":"Invalid JSON body","errorCode":"oanda::rest::core::ClientRequestException"}'.

If anyone uses OANDA, with a demo account, and has experienced the same situation, please help. Here is the developer guide I have been relying on: https://developer.oanda.com/rest-live-v20/order-ep/.
Also, I can successfully submit GET requests for data retrieval.
import requests

def submit_order():
   headers = {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       "Authorization": "Bearer " + [my access token]
   }
   submit_order_path = "https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/[my account number]/orders"

   formatted_order = {
   "order":{
      "type": "STOP",
      "instrument": "GBP_USD",
      "units": "10000",
      "price": "1.33606",
      "priceBound": "1.33606",
      "timeInForce": "GTD",
      "gtdTime": "2024-09-27 21:00:00",
      "positionFill": "DEFAULT",
      "triggerCondition": "DEFAULT",
      "clientExtensions": {
            "id": "V-ALPHA",
            "tag": "V-ALPHA",
            "comment": "V-ALPHA"
      },
      "takeProfitOnFill": {
            "price": "1.34374",
            "timeInForce": "GTD",
            "gtdTime": "2024-09-27 21:00:00"
      },
      "stopLossOnFill": {
            "price": "1.33016",
            "timeInForce": "GTD",
            "gtdTime": "2024-09-27 21:00:00"
      },
      "tradeClientExtensions": {
            "id": "V-ALPHA",
            "tag": "V-ALPHA",
            "comment": "V-ALPHA"
      }
    }
  }

  response = requests.post(url=submit_order_path, headers=headers, json=json.dumps(formatted_order))

  return response

I have tried to contact the OANDA Support Team but at no avail.
